# order by parameter value in case statement doesn't always work but if hard coded it does

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, case

If I pass in 'rating' to the @sortBy parameter it return the results as expected.
If I hard code the column name 'name' in the order by clause it returns the results as expected but when passed in to the @sortBy parameter it returns: 
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

I need it to work when 'name' is passed in.

```
DECLARE @sortBy         varchar(255) = N'name',
    @sortDirection  varchar(4) = N'D'       

SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY -- name DESC
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'A' THEN
            CASE 
               WHEN @sortBy = 'rating' THEN overallRating
               WHEN @sortBy = 'name' THEN name 
            END
        END ASC
        , CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'D' THEN
            CASE 
               WHEN @sortBy = 'rating' THEN overallRating
               WHEN @sortBy = 'name' THEN name 
            END
        END DESC

    ) AS RowNumber INTO #Results
FROM
(
    SELECT id
      , type
      , name
      , formatted_address
      , icon
      , reference
      , lat
      , lng
      , place_id
      , open_now
      , photo_reference
      , width
      , height
      , html_attribution
      , price_level
      , CASE WHEN 
            (SELECT AVG(rating)
            FROM reviews r
            WHERE r.places_id = place_id
            AND r.delete_check = 0) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN (
            (SELECT AVG(rating) 
            FROM reviews r
            WHERE r.places_id = place_id
            AND r.delete_check = 0) + cast(rating as float)) / 2
        ELSE
            rating
        END AS overallRating
    from search_places 
    where search_id = 12
  ) y

SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM #Results
SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20
DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it into four cases.

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/ZUZHO20174)**

```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'A' AND @sortBy = 'rating' THEN overallRating END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'A' AND @sortBy = 'name' THEN name END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'D' AND @sortBy = 'rating' THEN overallRating END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'D' AND @sortBy = 'name' THEN name END DESC)
```

And consider adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the query to [allow better index usage](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) if you have indexes that could potentially avoid a sort for one or more cases.

Comment: yes. I learn about it couple of weeks ago. Also use www.sqlFiddle.com because if you copy the data there, he create the DDL for you. But lately has been some problems so now use both.